# When you have no favorite tags, do we need 2 links?

Tags: feature-request, design, tag-watching

Just noticed on meta, where I don't have any favorite tags, that you get 2 links allowing you to add tags. Granted they give you slightly different options as you can see:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>edit</kbd> gives users the ability to add *Favorite Tags* and *Ignored Tags*.

<kbd>add...</kbd> only gives users the ability to add *Favorite Tags*.

Once you have saved at least one favorite tag, you lose the <kbd>add...</kbd> option altogether:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>.

So firstly, I'm not sure both links are required. Either they swap when there are/aren't tags present or we lose the <kbd>add...</kbd> link altoghether.

Secondly, the '**A**' in ***A**dd a favorite tag* and ***A**dd an ignored tag* is capitalized, which I guess should be lower case like every other link of that style.